# Deserializing dictionary-like JSON with extra property on same nesting depth

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to deserialize a JSON API payload into a C# object. The problem is because the response looks like this:

```
{
    "2023-09-14": {
        "slots": [
            "2023-09-14T08:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T08:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T09:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T09:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T10:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T10:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T11:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T11:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T12:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T12:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T13:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T13:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T14:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T14:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T15:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T15:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T16:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T16:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T17:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T17:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T18:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T18:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T19:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T19:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T20:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-14T20:30:00-04:00"
        ]
    },
    "2023-09-15": {
        "slots": [
            "2023-09-15T08:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T08:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T09:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T09:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T10:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T10:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T11:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T11:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T12:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T12:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T13:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T13:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T14:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T14:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T15:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T15:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T16:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T16:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T17:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T17:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T18:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T18:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T19:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T19:30:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T20:00:00-04:00",
            "2023-09-15T20:30:00-04:00"
        ]
    },
    "traceId": "344fea8b-06a4-49c0-be69-753060ad91cf"
}
```

As you can see, the response is structured like a dictionary, with keys being the dates. The only problem is the traceId.

My current idea right now is to use a Dictionary<string, JsonElement>, then deserialize each individual JsonElement to the object I need.

My solution using Dictionary<string, JsonElement> did not work, and the elements of the dictionary are null. This is the object I am deserializing each JsonElement into:

```
public class FreeSlots
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public FreeSlots(){}

        [JsonPropertyName("slots")]       
        public List<string>? slots;
    }
```

If anyone has any insight into a solution, I would really appreciate it. I am using System.Text.Json library.

Comment: The json is not a dictionary - it's an object with 3 properties.  Paste your code here - https://json2csharp.com/ to see the resulting c sharp classes. The problem you have is that 2 of the top level fields don't have fixed property names (unlike TraceId) - they're data time values.  This makes it pretty much impossible to deserialize to a fixed class structure. Do you have control over the json so that the date time fields are values to a fixed property name ?

Comment: @auburg I dont have control over the json; this is from an external API. However I just discovered something that might be a solution to keep a fixed class structure, using the [JsonExtensionData] property on a Dictionary<string, FreeSlots> property in the class definition, or perhaps Dictionary<DateTime, FreeSlots> if such a deserialization is feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this, but it's not pretty neat either

```
public class FreeSlots : IJsonOnDeserialized
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public Dictionary<string, JsonElement> InnerDictionary { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Dictionary<DateTime, SlotsItem> Slots { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("traceId")]
    public Guid TraceId { get; set; }

    public void OnDeserialized()
    {
        this.Slots = new Dictionary<DateTime, SlotsItem>();

        foreach (var pair in this.InnerDictionary)
        {
            var date = DateTime.Parse(pair.Key, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var slot = pair.Value.Deserialize<SlotsItem>();

            this.Slots[date] = slot;
        }
    }
}

public class SlotsItem
{
    [JsonPropertyName("slots")]
    public DateTime[] Slots { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this is what i'm trying now:

```
public class FreeSlotsResponse
    {
        public class FreeSlots
        {
            [JsonConstructor]
            public FreeSlots(){}

            [JsonPropertyName("slots")]       
            public List<string>? slots;
        }

        [JsonConstructor]
        public FreeSlotsResponse(){}

        [JsonExtensionData]
        public Dictionary<string, FreeSlots>? Dates { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("traceId")]
        public string? TraceId { get; set; }
    }
```